# ActiveMQ shuts down on startup with "TERM Trapped"

Tags: java, jenkins, activemq-classic, java-service-wrapper

I'm currently using the java service wrapper to start my ActiveMQ (5.10) service running on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. Every now and then when my Jenkins instance runs the last step in my deploy script

```
cd /app/apache-activemq-5.10.0/bin/linux-x86-64; ./activemq restart
```

the wrapper will try to start up, then immediately shutdown with the following log entries.

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/10/09 08:15:09 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/10/09 08:15:09 | Launching a JVM...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/10/09 08:15:09 | TERM trapped.  Shutting down.
WARN   | wrapper  | 2014/10/09 08:15:09 | JVM exited unexpectedly while stopping the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/10/09 08:15:09 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I haven't got a clue why this is happening. Ideas anyone?

Comment: Found anything out?

Comment: This was so long ago, but it might have been related to this https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller